# Swift - Async calls in loop

Tags: swift, loops, asynchronous

I hope you are doing fine.
I am trying to achieve following thing:

1. Fetch data array from database (async call)
2. Iterate over fetched data array
3. Fetch additional information about each object (async call)
4. Create a new data array with all the information and return it back

Currently, I have following approach

```
self.dataAccessService.fetchRepliesByCommentId(completionHandler: { (commentReplyArray) in
  for var i in 0..<commentReplyArray.count {
    let commentReply = commentReplyArray[i]
    let commentItem = CommentItem()
     
    self.fetchDetailsAboutCommentReply(commentReplyObject: commentReply) { (commentItem) in
      commentItem.commentObject = commentReply
       
      dataSource.insert(commentItem, at: index + i + 1) -> APP CRASHES HERE, i is never 0 here
      ips.append(IndexPath(row: index + i + 1 , section: 0))
                                                      
      if (i == commentReplyArray.count - 1) {
        self.delegate?.didLoadReplies(dataSource: dataSource, ips: ips)
      }
    }
  }
}, commentId: commentItem.commentObject.id)
```

My fetchDetailsAboutCommentReply function:

```
private func fetchDetailsAboutCommentReply(commentReplyObject:CommentReply, completionHandler:@escaping(CommentItem)->()) {
 let group = DispatchGroup()
 let commentItem = CommentItem()
 
 group.enter()
  self.dataAccessService.fetchUserById(completionHandler: { (userObject) in
    commentItem.userObject = userObject
    group.leave()
 }, uid: commentReplyObject.userId)
        
 group.enter()
  self.dataAccessService.fetchDownloadURLOfProfileImage(organizerId: commentReplyObject.userId) { (contentURL) in
  commentItem.userObject.contentURL = contentURL
  group.leave()
 }
 
group.notify(queue: .main) {
  completionHandler(commentItem)
}
```

}

My question is how, I can change my code, so the loop basically "pauses" until I fetch every detail information of the iterated object, add it into the dataSource Array and then continues with the next one?

Thanks and stay healthy!

Comment: Google “DispatchGroup”.

Comment: Hi @matt , I used DispatchGroup already. See my second code snippet

Comment: But you didn’t use it for the loop.

Comment: Minor point, but I would advise against `for var i in ...` syntax unless `i` is really mutable, which it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It is exceedingly hard to be specific because we do not have information about your data source logic, the types, etc. But, then again, I do not think we want to get into that here, anyway.

So, some general observations:

- You should use `DispatchGroup` in the loop. E.g.,

  ```
  let group = DispatchGroup()
  for i in ... {
      group.enter()
      someAsyncMethod { completion in
          defer { group.leave() }
          ...
      }
  }
  group.notify(queue: .main) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- As you can see, I have removed that `if (i == commentReplyArray.count - 1) { ... }` test because you want these to run in parallel and just because the “last” one finished doesn't mean that they've all finished. Use the `DispatchGroup` and its `notify` method to know when they're all done.
- I am suspicious about that `+ 1` logic in your `dataSource.insert` call (we live in a zero-based-index world). E.g. the first item you insert should have an index of `0`, not `1`. (And if you are doing that `+ 1` logic because you have some extra cell in your tableview/collection view, I would suggest not entangling that offset index logic inside this routine, but let your “data source” take care of that.)
- That probably doesn't matter because you really want to refactor this data source, anyway, so it doesn't matter the order that the `fetchDetailsAboutComent` completion handlers are called. E.g., build a local dictionary, and when done, build your sorted array and pass that back:

  ```
  // dictionary for results, so order doesn't matter

  var results: [Int: CommentReply] = [:]  // I don't know what the type of your comment/reply is, so adjust this as needed

  let group = DispatchGroup()
  for i in 0..<20 {
      group.enter()
      someAsyncMethod { completion in
          defer { group.leave() }
          ...
          results[i] = ...
      }
  }

  group.notify(queue: .main) {
      // now build array from the dictionary

      let array = (0..<20).compactMap { results[i] }

      dataSource?.insert(array)
      ...
  }
  ```

  If you really want to call the data source as results come in, you can theoretically do that, but you want to make sure that you're not just inserting into an array but rather that the `dataSource` object can handle the results as they come in, out of order.

  You suggest that you want the loop to “pause” for one request until the prior one finishes, and I would strenuously advise against that pattern, as it will make the process far slower (basically compounding network latency effects). You really want logic that can let the requests run in parallel.

Comment: Do you find that `defer { group.leave() }` actually works? Seems like a great use of defer but in my experience it’s unreliable.

Comment: Yes, I always use `defer { group.leave() }` and it's rock-solid in my experience. I prefer this pattern because (a) it puts the `leave` visually closer to the `enter`, making it easier for me to reason about the code; and (b) it gets me out of tracking every little early-exit (e.g. `guard`, `if`, and `switch` statements) to make sure there wasn't a path of execution that I overlooked. The only case where you can't use this simple `defer` pattern for `leave` is those cases where the subsequent code is initiating yet another asynchronous call.

Comment: Hi @Rob. Well, basically, I provide the whole data source with the comments and to one given comment, I want to load all the replies. This could be one reply or multiple ones. Let's say, there are three replies in that commentReplyArray. How, do I know that I got all the information of all three replies? Once group.notify(queue: .main) is called, I might only have one reply or?

Comment: You’ve got two dispatch group types, one in `fetchDetailsAboutCommentReply` (which makes sure that you don’t call the its completion handler until these inner two asynchronous requests finish) and one in the loop where you call `fetchDetailsAboutCommentReply` repeatedly, so that outer `notify` won’t be invoked until _all_ of the requests finish.